# intellij idea кодировка

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Помогите решить проблему с кодировкой. Вывод результата выполнения ping в корявой кодировке, если `System.out.println("Привет\nПока");`  - то всё нормально.

```
    @PostMapping("/ping")
    public String ping (String ping, String tracert, String whois, Map<String, Object> model) {
    String ip = "127.0.0.1";
    String pingResult = "";
    String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            pingResult += inputLine;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("Привет\nПока");
    return "tech.html";
}
```

Пробовал добавлять -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8 и -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 в idea64.exe.vmoption, редактировать настройки Idea, но никак.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как это ни странно, но многие консольные утилиты по умолчанию работают в кодировке "CP866":

```java
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "CP866"));
```